# Need to keep the toggle active on page load and also hide it when page loads

Tags: javascript

On this page [click here](https://www.etihad.com/en/book/book-with-etihad-guest-miles), there is a toggle next to the text **Book with miles**.

I need this toggle to be on the checked (active) position by default using javascript and also hide it on the page. so that by default the toggle is active and hidden on the page.

This is the image of the page - The toggle is golden when in active form

[image]

Comment: Do you want to have this option checked by default and remove the choice for the user ?

Comment: Yes JB_DELR I need the option to be checked by default and remove the choice for user

Comment: On this website, is this yours ? do you have access to the source ?

Comment: Yes I have access to the A/B testing tool (Adobe Target) so it will force a javascript custom code on the page.

Comment: Try this:
document.querySelector('.switch-btn').click();
document.querySelector('.switch').style.display = 'none'
But this do the thing on all switch-btn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('redemptionsearchslider').nextSibling.click();
document.getElementById('redemptionsearchslider').parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
```

or as you have jQuery:

```
jQuery('#redemptionsearchslider').click()
jQuery('#redemptionsearchslider')[0].parentElement.parentElement.style.display = 'none'
```

Answer (score 0):

For toggling you must be using one boolean variable. Keep the varaible default value **true** on page load.

For hiding the toggle check from UI, you can use CSS and javascript.

```
document.getElementById("element").style.display = "none";
```

To show the toggle (in case if you want)

```
document.getElementById("element").style.display = "block";
```